# Exclude many files and folders using Robocopy

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, robocopy

I have a robocopy job, mainly copying `C:\src` to `D:\dst`.

The problem is that there are many, many directories in `C:\src`, which I want to exclude (eg. output directories of dev projects, repositories etc.), which means, that I have a robocopy command like this:

```
robocopy C:\src D:\dst /COPY:DAT /E /XD <dir1> /XD <dir2> ... /XD <dirN>
```

But when I added the newest dirs to exclude, Windows complains that the command gets too long!
Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been answered before here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/510482/how-do-i-use-robocopy-with-a-large-number-of-excluded-files

In short, create a job file by running a robocopy command with just some folders to exclude

```
robocopy src dst /S /XD skipdir /save:rcjob
```

and edit the file created. In this file, you can enter one folder to exclude per line, without being limited by the command line buffer length.
Then run robocopy with the modified job file:

```
robocopy /job:rcjob
```

Comment: That's awesome!!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you may be able to do to reduce the length of the command. From what I can find, there is no way to allow unlimited excludes.

Try the following:

- You can list multiple directories after a single `/XD`.

  ```
  robocopy C:\src D:\dst /COPY:DAT /E /XD <dir1> <dir2> ... <dirN>
  ```
- Use wildcards where you can. The following line will exclude `dir1`, `dir2`, etc.

  ```
  robocopy C:\src D:\dst /COPY:DAT /E /XD dir*
  ```

  The following line will exclude `C:\src\this_dir`, `C:\src\that_dir`, `C:\src\test\subdir`, etc.

  ```
  robocopy C:\src D:\dst /COPY:DAT /E /XD *dir
  ```

Comment: This is very promising. Is there any way to wildcard *dirB in dirA*? When I write `/XD dirA\dirB`, it doesn't exclude any `dirB`, when I write `/XD *\dirA\dirB`, it gives *Invalid parameter*.

Comment: It seems `robocopy` doesn't support path names in the `/XD` or `/XF` switches. Even if I use `/XD dirA\dirB`, `dirB` is still copied. You could try using `xcopy` instead. Its `/EXCLUDE:` switch seems to support wildcards *and* paths, but it doesn't support the same `/COPY:` functionality that `robocopy` has.

Comment: :-( Seems that I have to use `rsync` instead when the command gets too long again. With your tips I got it at least *a bit* shorter for the moment.